# Show a objection reflection onto another surface in Blender internal

Tags: opengl

I will show a objection reflection onto another flat surface in Blender internal, Material viewport because I will like to try and use the opengl render.

I tried using mirror but it wont show up in the Material viewrport, only show up in Rendered viewport.

Is there other way? Please advise.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to bake it. or do you need moving parts over it, as in the game engine?

Comment: There will be moving parts, thus will need it to be dynamic.